# ModelMapper skip a field

Tags: modelmapper

I would like to map between `UserDTO` and `User`, but excluding one field, say `city`. How can I do that, cause I though that this approach would work, but it doesn't:

```
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

modelMapper.typeMap(UserDTO.class,User.class).addMappings(mp -> {
    mp.skip(User::setCity);
});
```

Comment: Could you show the example when it doesn't work?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @MuhammedOzdogan - Why you think it will solve the problem? I have the same problem.

Comment: @SanjeevDhiman Did you try without lambda expression?

Comment: city is in user or DTO?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because of the generic parameters, we couldn't use the lambda expression.

```
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
modelMapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<Dto, Source>() {
                @Override
                protected void configure() {
                    skip(destination.getBlessedField());
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 7):

For the configuration to work need to add:

`modelMapper.getConfiguration().setAmbiguityIgnored(true);`

E.g.

```
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
modelMapper.getConfiguration().setAmbiguityIgnored(true);
modelMapper.addMappings(clientPropertyMap);
modelMapper.map(UserDTO, User);


PropertyMap<UserDTO, User> clientPropertyMap = new PropertyMap<UserDTO, User>() {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        skip(destination.getCity());
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> For the configuration to work need to add: 
> modelMapper.getConfiguration().setAmbiguityIgnored(true);

This is true only when the destination field matches to multiple source fields. Skipping the setting of a destination field will work without the above if there is either a 1-1 or a 0-1 match between source-destination.