# How can i create two different map methods with ModelMapper for the same Source and Destination

Tags: java, modelmapper

Let's say i have the following classes

```
class User {
   private String name:
   private Address address;
  // getters and setters
}

class UserDto {
   private String name:
   private Address address;
  // getters and setters
}
```

I already have created a [modelMapper](https://modelmapper.org/) that allows me to do the following :

UserDto userDto = modelMapper.map(user, UserDto.class); // this map function map every field in the User class to UserDto class

And i would like to create a modelMapper that allows me to do the following :

UserDto userDto = modelMapper.mapWithoutAddress(user, UserDto.class); // this map function map every field except the adress from the User class to UserDto class

NB: i'am using a ModelMapper Singleton, i'm using the same instance in all my application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModelMapper skip a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49074784/modelmapper-skip-a-field)

Comment: Hello @daniu, i saw that question and i didn't find a satisfying answer

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/property-mapping/#skipping-properties) said, you could skip the property.

```
modelMapper.typeMap(User.class, UserDto.class).addMappings(mapper -> mapper.skip(UserDto::setAddress));
```

Comment: It works for one case, but since I am using a singleton of ModelMapper, this skip configuration impacts the first map method which doesn't map the address anymore. Ideally i would like a separate map method